# What are These Outbound Network Rules

Tags: networking, vpn, rules

I Have a few odd looking network outbound rules for my computer they are

```
Name                          Group                           Application Package

f5.vpn.client                 f5.vpn.client                   f5.vpn.client_cw5n1h2txyewy
CheckPoint.VPN                CheckPoint.VPN                  CheckPoint.VPN_cw5n1h2txyewy
JuniperNetworks.JunosPulseVpn JuniperNetworks.JunosPulseVpn   JuniperNetworks.JunosPulseVpn_cw5n1h2txyewy
```

What are there can you please tell me what they are
Thanks